# Write once read many in memory key value store

Tags: database, key-value, in-memory-database, key-value-store

I have a particular use case for multiple in memory key value maps that need very fast lookup time. They are set just set once a day so can be considered immutable for all practical purposes. Redis is not an option since it gets CPU throttled in case of multiple threads accessing it. Multi instance redis takes up too much memory because of data replication. The important thing to consider here is that the read rate is very high in bursts. Around 10 million requests in bursts from around 40-50 workers simultaneously.

I was thinking of creating a simple client server architecture with multiple readers connecting to a server to read from shared memory maps. However I wonder if such an architecture already exists and has been tested profusely for this use case in which case I should not be reinventing the wheel.

So to sum up what is my best alternative? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be suitable for you but you could try [RBLDNSD](http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/rbldnsd.html) and store your values in DNS. It's high performance and results will be cached, and it's easy to read the values from pretty much any programming environment. To write values to it you'll need to write directly to its zone files, but the format is simple and easy to write.

Comment: Will check it out although I do not think this is the right usage for this framework.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the size of your maps, but given that performance is so critical, it sounds like you may want to consider keeping copies of your 'multiple in memory key value maps' with each worker.

You could then implement a simple mechanism to notify each worker that it's time to refresh their maps (e.g. Redis PUBLISH, or any other pubsub type framework).

Comment: Map sizes range from a few thousand to around 20 million entries in the largest map. The total memory footprint in case of redis is around 9GB. I do not have that much spare memory on each worker. The workers are running spark jobs which are pretty memory intensive themselves.

Comment: Do all workers need access to all the data?  Can you partition the dataset such that each worker has only the *chunks* required?  When assigning a task to a worker can you prefer workers that have already worked with a similar task?  Can you use an in-memory cache for hot data and use Redis as a slower network cache, much like [stackoverflow.com does](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69164/does-stack-exchange-use-caching-and-if-so-how)

Comment: Map access is pretty random. I do not think I can partition based on that. However you did mention the hot cache mechanism which I have not tried as of yet mainly because I do not know how many repetitive queries are there. My assumption was that the repetition is low but I may well be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of running afoul of the stackoverlow self-promotion police :-)  eXtremeDB might be a consideration.  It's not schema-less, but your schema can simply define a key-value pair.  It supports MVCC (optimistic, non-blocking) concurrency so even the relatively infrequent writes won't get in the way of readers, and you'll be able to utilize all the CPU cores.

Comment: Is this open source?

Comment: @Sohaib Doesn't look like it's open source.

Comment: Right, it is not open source, though a source code license is an option.